# Getting stock graphs from yahoo finance

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-finance

I am using yahoo finance to get stock quotes. Now i want to get the graph of a particular company. Is it possible to do this using yahoo. If not could someone please provide some other api through which one could achieve this. ( the 20 minute delay is not an issue at all). I am looking for stocks listed in bse and nse.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yahoo Finance API lets you retrieve graphs of stocks.

The main url is `https://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=AAPL&t=6m&q=l&l=on&z=s&p=m50,m200`

For options to use, please refer to this [page](http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/miscapiImageDownload).

The result is a picture, so you just have to write (for eg in HTML):

`<img src="https://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=AAPL&t=6m&q=l&l=on&z=s&p=m50,m200"/>`

to display:

[image]

Please note that I'm not sure if Yahoo Finance supports stocks for India, http://in.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=%5EBSESN and http://in.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5ENSEI don't seem to display list of components...

Comment: link for options is out of date, but this endpoint still works. any suggestions for another source?

Comment: See here for more, though I haven't tried them: http://blog.habrador.com/2013/10/how-to-add-stock-charts-to-your-website.html

Comment: Archived link of Yahoo Finance options: http://web.archive.org/web/20160702182327/https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/miscapiImageDownload

Comment: this is out of date

Answer (score 0):

I am using Linux to get tickers/stock into Gnucash. My Finance::Quote, Cpan. Perl are all up to date, Gnucash wont see it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).